# Shortcuts for editing "Name" and "Text" on UI elements in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a WinForms project, and I'm wondering if there are any shortcuts for editing the "Name" property and Text property for controls added to a form. It's extremely painstaking when adding labels that you add the label, then have to scroll through the properties to the "Text" field and the "Name" field in the "Properties" window.

It seems like there has got to be an easier way. Looked around for videos, but it feels like there has got to be a better way. Textboxes have a little triangle that let you change them to multiline, but setting the name and text for a control seem to be tasks that happen every time you add a control.

Comment: I don't think any such shortcuts exist. I wish they did. Here's my "hack": I modify one property at a time across many controls. First, select "(Name)" in the Properties tool window. Then click a control and start typing. It'll move the focus to Properties where "(Name)" will start editing. Click another control and start typing, and so on. Once that property is set everywhere, select "Text" and do the same through through the controls. It may not be the way one is wont to think but it eases the scrolling and the clicking a bit.

Comment: If you select, in the Designer, a Control that can show Text and you begin typing, you'll change its Text (usually, the default property). If you get used to Form / Control templates, you name the Controls once, then use templates as the base of other Forms / Controls. Otherwise, you can drop Controls on a Form, to see how the Layout may go, then open up the Document Outline panel (`View -> Other Windows -> Document Outline`). This tool will show you all the Controls in a Form and, when you select one, its position. Press F2 as usual to rename a Control. Assign event handlers after.

Comment: I believe this can be done with macros. To do this, you need some [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=macros&target=VS&category=Tools&vsVersion=&subCategory=All&sortBy=Relevance) for Visual Studio to support macros. However, you need to find an old-school specialist who still remembers the [DTE2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte80.dte2?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) interface.

Comment: @Jimi - Thank you. Can you post your comment as an "answer"? Using the Document Outline view with F2 is great. In your comment you say "Press F2 as usual to rename a control", I'm not sure what you mean by "as usual". Where else does F2 rename a control?

I wish design view could be set up to prompt you to name the control as you add each one to the form.